# Why the browser doesn't send cookies while requesting a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, cookies

I'm loading [site1]/script.js on [site2]/page.html with `script` tag.
And the browser does not send cookies while requesting a JS file.

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 14:45:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 544
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Location: script.js.php
Vary: negotiate,Accept-Encoding
TCN: choice
Set-Cookie: test_id=551d5612406cd; expires=Sat, 02-Apr-2016 14:45:38 GMT; path=/
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Request headers - no cookies:

```
GET /script.js HTTP/1.1
Host: [site1]
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: [site2]/page.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,sk;q=0.
```

Comment: Cookies aren't shared between domains (the type of resource doesn't matter). Why do you need to share cookies?

Comment: Because if the browser sent your cookie across domains, then there's be nothing stopping nastycriminalsite.ru from stealing your localbank.com login cookie.

Comment: Because of [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it was my mistake. Google Chrome was blocking third-party cookies.

By default browser send cookies with JavaScript file request.

Answer (score 15):

There is a special case where cookies are not sent, even though the origin is the same: when loading ES6 modules!

```
<script type="module" src="some-script.js"></script>
```

This won't send cookies, so it might fail if your server needs to authenticate requests.

As [this excellent article points out](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), you need to explicitly require credentials to be sent by adding the 
`crossorigin` attribute:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="some-script.js"></script>
```

This behavior is currently considered a bug (it doesn't make any sense, right?) and it's being fixed in all major browsers. See the link above for more details.

Comment: We had this problem in Safari. It still didn't sent the cookies with `crossorigin`, but it did with `crossorigin="use-credentials"`.

Comment: As of 2020, this still is happening with Safari, and this answer is very helpful. @Alexander Matveev, I am aware that your actual problem was a different one, but your question pops up first when researching this issue. Perhaps it would be useful if you changed the accepted answer to this one, as it is the one providing a solution...

Answer (score 6):

Browsers **do** send cookies when requesting JavaScript files, just as they do when requesting anything else. And the same rules apply: The cookie must be for the origin/path. In your example, you seem to be using two different origins (`site1` and `site2`), which would explain why you don't see the cookie in the request.

For instance: I set up a page called `test.php` on my server that sets a cookie. It then has a link to `test2.html` which includes `foo.js`. These are all on the same path (`/`, in my example, because I'm lazy and didn't create a subdirectory for the test).

In the response headers when the browser gets `test.php`, I see

```
Set-Cookie:test=123
```

If I then click to `test2.html`, I see this in the request headers for `test2.html`:

```
Cookie:test=123
```

And then I see the request for `foo.js`, and in that request I see:

```
Cookie:test=123
```